# Is it possible to run `oc cluster up` offline?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-client-tools

I'm trying to run `oc cluster up` - the Openshift 3.11 development environment - in an offline environment.

I have run it previously while online, and so the required images are downloaded.

Then I modified these files and set

- ./openshift.local.clusterup/static-pod-manifests/apiserver.yaml
- ./openshift.local.clusterup/static-pod-manifests/etcd.yaml
- ./openshift.local.clusterup/static-pod-manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml
- ./openshift.local.clusterup/static-pod-manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml

And set `imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent`.

However, when subsequently running `oc cluster up` the files are written over, and again set to `imagePullPolicy: Always`.

I then tried setting the above files to be eadonly, but the `oc cluster up` fails with a permission error.

## Update

I found that the following command - `oc cluster up --tag=v3.11` - will create `.yaml` that include `imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent` however `oc cluster up` still fails to start without internet access.